# JSP make array list public

Tags: java, arrays, jsp

i am trying to out put an array on screen. but the array (ans) is not being recognised. jsp is very new to me. 
i want the array list to be public like java.
is this possible?

i need to declare the array in the jsp bit. so i can display it and the bottom. 
how do i do that.

here is my code.

```
<%
SimpleDataSource.init("database.properties");

Connection con = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();
try {
    PreparedStatement pst = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM    Quiz2");
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    //ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();

    int i = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        ans[i] = rs.getString(1);
        i++;
    }
} finally {
    con.close();
}
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <h2>ans</h2>   //output array here. 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ummmm... that does not look like PHP to me....

Answer (score 0):

That is not PHP code. However, the *ans* array declaration is commented so that code is not working.